# trying to use history.js via cdn and getting Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, history.js

I am trying to use history.js lib via cdn. On the docs it says the library can be accessed via `window.Histroy`. Following the docs I tried the following,
`window.History.createBrowserHistory()` and it says that thats not a function. I then logged `window.History` and saw that it is a function itself, so I tried `window.History()` and this turns out is an Illegal constructor.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) to the docs.

My question is, how does one use the history.js lib via cdn?

Comment: Bad docs, you want the UMD instead ~ https://unpkg.com/history/umd/history.min.js. The docs appear better on their NPM page https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

Comment: this helped thanks.